# Nested hash in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to run a command over nested hash. I am unable to come to a solution. I have tried using `with_items`,  `with_dict` But I believe that does not fit my use case.

On going though the ansible loops I think I can accomplish this using [loop-control](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control). How ever I could not achieve it. Can someone please help me out here.

Ansible Version: 2.0.2.0

My hash

```
users:
  ankit:
    name: ankit
    access:
      opt: /opt/data
      tmp: /tmp
  gupta:
    name: gupta
    access:
      data: /opt/data/gupta
```

Expected execution to be run in a loop using the above hash.

```
- file: path=/opt/data state=directory owner:ankit mode=0755
- file: path=/tmp state=directory owner:ankit mode=0755
- file: path=/opt/data/gupta state=directory owner:gupta mode=0755
```

Note:  This is a modified example. I am not creating folders in the actual task. I am creating Kafka topics if it does not exist based on Storm Topology. How ever the hash structure is the same and my need to use these Items

Re-posted the question with actual facts (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37182895/nested-hash-in-ansible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My mistake was I was trying to use [loop_control](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control) with Ansible 2.0 hence it was not working. instead I should be using [loops-and-includes-in-2-0](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loops-and-includes-in-2-0) and `set_fact`.

main.yml

```
- include: kafka_topic.yml
  with_dict: project.topology
```

kafka_topic.yml

```
- set_fact:
    outer_item: "{{item}}"

- debug:
    msg: "inner item={{item.value}}"
    with_dict: outer_item.value.kafka_topic
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no standard loop which allows you to do this with your data structure.

`with_dict` will not process subelements. `with_subelements` *would* work if you'd have a list and not a dict. With this data structure:

```
users:
  - name: ankit
    access:
      - /opt/data
      - /tmp
  - name: gupta
    access:
      - /opt/data/gupta
```

... you could do something like this:

```
- file: "path={{ item.1 }} state=directory owner={{ item.0.name }} mode=0755"
  with_subelements:
     - "{{ users }}"
     - access
```

If you can not change your data structure it will get more complex. You can use some ugly workaround like first using `with_dict` looping over the users together with an `include` task and then have another `with_dict` in the included file where you loop over the *access*-items.

Or do it the right/clean way and [create your own lookup plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#lookup-plugins). With little python knowledge you can loop over any data structure.

Comment: I cannot change the structure as I use the same hash for other tasks where I need the folders names based on the work. i.e in my template files I am using  `users.ankit.access.opt`,   `users.gupta.access.data` etc. 

Note: this is a modified example. I am not creating folders in the actual task. I am creating Kafka topics if it does not exist based on Storm Topology. How ever the hash structure is the same and my need to use these Items

Comment: Then the best option would be a custom lookup plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My mistake was I was trying to use [loop_control](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loop-control) with Ansible 2.0 hence it was not working. instead I should be using [loops-and-includes-in-2-0](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#loops-and-includes-in-2-0) and `set_fact`.